# Diagnosing root cause of single core failure

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure

I have a strange issue with a new system comprising of Ryzen 3700X and ASUS TUF X570 (WiFi).

I was able to boot the system, install Windows on an NVMe and then start and run Windows. After a couple of days of use the system shut down unexpectedly. From this point onwards I have not been able to fully boot any operating system. Windows on a known working HDD, the new Windows NVMe install, a Windows USB Recovery and Ubuntu on a seperate HDD all fail to boot.

Concerned that I had something loose I reseated every connector in the system. I then replaced the GPU with a different working GPU in a different PCIe slot. I reseated the memory, tried running with a both single sticks in different ports. I also used a different known working PSU, detached all external cables other than a single keyboard, DisplayPort, and internal NVMe/USB Boot Drive. The problem persisted.

Finally I managed to run Memtest86, on the default configuration the tests would run for a few seconds before creating a stream of errors and ending due to too many errors, hanging, or resetting the system. Often the errors identified a single CPU (14) as the issue.

I then ran Memtest on single CPU mode, this passed fine for all cores 0-13, but 14 and 15 always hung immediately. My BIOS allows the CPU to run in 2, 4, 6 or default(8) core mode, after selecting just two cores I can again boot and run the OS.

I assume these issues are pointing to a chipset issue, without swapping the motherboard or CPU, is there a way to determine which is at fault? How much does the motherboard take part in core selection and memory management on such a system?

Comment: The memory interface is entirely in the CPU. If you have memory errors from specific CPU cores then the CPU is defective.

Comment: If you're correct that seems to be a incontrovertible reasoning. Could you add that as an answer, do you have any references? I think I should highlight some details of the failure: Memtest allows one to choose the cpu on which the test runs. Running on cores 0-13 passes without errors, cores 14 and 15 hang immediately, there are no errors reported as the application is hung. Running with multiple cores creates errors, then a quit, reset or hang.

Comment: I believe the Memtest I was running is also using UEFI, could a firmware bug in the bios cause these errors in that case....?

Comment: I would be surprised at a firmware bug that specific, but it could be worth checking for updates. I've posted an answer explaining why I think this is a CPU core defect.

Comment: My guess is (as it seems you assembled that computer yourself) that you did not take ESD precautions when touching the components (and thus damaged those). Many people seem ignorant about those. For examples see https://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=ideas-and-advice/esd-protection-guide or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84961/what-are-esd-electrostatic-discharge-precautions

Comment: I took some precautions, such as not wearing synthetic clothing and regularly touching a grounded object. I didn't go as far as wearing a ESD wristband though. While possible that this could have damaged components I think it's unlikely due to the nature of the failure. I never touched any CPU pins due to their fragile nature and the failure occurred within a core that does not have an external electrical interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your testing points very strongly towards a damaged CPU core. Not the entire processor or even motherboard, a specific *core*. Either it has an address or data bus fault and it simply cannot properly access RAM.

The reason I say that is because you mention CPU 14 & 15 causing Memtest to "hang immediately". If it were a motherboard fault then I would expect no cores at all to work.

The memory controller on modern systems is built directly into the CPU package. It passes through the motherboard directly to the memory sticks. If the motherboard had a memory fault then it wouldn't matter which core was accessing it, they should all get errors as the actual memory bus is common to all cores.

The second damning thing is that it is cores 14 *and* 15. The [3700X](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-3700x) is 8 cores and 16 threads. So one core with a fault will affect two threads. It's not that only one thread is affected, it's both. That core itself likely has a fault, not just the thread logic around the core.

The fact that other cores are fine shows that the memory controller works and is "good", as is the internal inter-core bus within the CPU package. That specific cores do not function shows a worrying fault on those specific cores. It ***might*** be a timing problem within the CPU (cores further from the memory controller having a problem) that could be fixed with a firmware microcode update (but I doubt it), or it (most likely) is a permanent physical fault.

The erratic behaviour when in multi core mode is simply the program shuffling randomly across cores, it's fine on the good cores, but program or data errors occur on the bad ones.

To show the structure of a modern computer below is the general arrangement of an AMD chipset system taken from [Guru3D](https://www.guru3d.com/news-story/amd-ryzen-3000-new-block-diagram-about-pcie-4-on-matisse-and-x570-chipset.html). Notice that the CPU has become the true "core" of the system, with the memory and graphics being directly connected and the PCH relegated to handling various external devices.  Modern CPUs have a lot more integration  than they had 20 years ago.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer.

Comment: For anyone who has a defective core with a ryzen cpu, mind that lowering number of cores can revive the cpu. The gotcha, however, is it will disable even the good ones numerically above the defective one. I have a 5900x (ccx0,ccx1 upto 6 cores each) with ccx0,core3 defective. I had to set number of cores per ccx to 3. So (ccx0: 3,4,5; ccx1: 9,10,11) are disabled. Now I have a 6 core 64MB L3 cache 5900x (a buff 5600X really). Lowering core count per ccx to 3 would work in @mfurseman's case, his CPU too would become a 5600X in this case. If can't RMA (e.g. bought second hand), give it a try.

Comment: Better yet, on linux I used `isolcpus=7,8` to properly discard defective threads from being scheduled by the OS. `stress-ng` and `btop` confirm that those threads indeed have 0% load. Ok this ain't the question but wanted to point to a more practical solution.

Comment: My assumption of the linear numbering was wrong on ryzen ccx's. Installing an operating system is a good enough test to see if a core fails. Putting a Youtube video about it and a blog post too probably. I guess 0,1-4,5-8,9--2,3-6,7-10-11 is the order on ccx0. Likewise 12,13-16-17-20,21--14,15-18,19-22,23 on ccx1. Thus, 3 cores per each ccx worked with my faulty 2,3 and 14,15. Lastly, 7,8 is not a single core, I failed at math up there :D