# thousands of errors on memtest86+

Tags: memory, cpu, bsod, memtest86+

I recently started having random BSODs that coincided with a Windows installation that became increasingly unstable.

I upgraded the NVMe and reinstalled Windows from scratch.
BSODs are sadly still there.

I ran into weird issues since then as well: it seems like the system tends to boot directly into Windows (especially if there is a USB stick plugged in) and I struggle to get into the BIOS. I basically get a black screen most of the time instead of POST, even when I press DEL to go into the BIOS.

The on/off button LED also mysteriously stopped working (but works again now, no idea why).

I am running four 16GB DDR4 sticks (3600MHz) with a Ryzen 3950X.

I managed to finally get into the bios and run MemTest86+ for a short time, it immediately returned hundreds then thousands of errors.

While I cut the test short, all the errors seem to be linked to CPU 13 and sometimes CPU 0.

- 2023-09-18 14:23:37 - [MEM ERROR - Data] Test: 1, CPU: 0, Address: 5B2020100, Expected: 00000005B2020100, Actual: 0000000592020100
- 2023-09-18 14:23:50 - [MEM ERROR - Data] Test: 2, CPU: 13, Address: 5B2020100, Expected: 00000005B2020100, Actual: 0000000592020100
- 2023-09-18 14:24:07 - [MEM ERROR - Data] Test: 3, CPU: 13, Address: 5B2020110, Expected: 00000000, Actual: 20000000
- 2023-09-18 14:25:32 - [MEM ERROR - Data] Test: 4, CPU: 13, Address: 5B2020110, Expected: 80808080, Actual: A0808080

Could this indicate an issue with the CPU rather than the memory sticks?

The system has been running fine for over 3 years.

I recently had an incident while trying to replace the thermal pad on the NVMe that sits below the CPU cooler, and it led to the CPU being unseated.
I did not realise this, the system couldn't boot for a while until I reseated the CPU. Then it worked fine for nearly 3 months and BSODs only appeared recently.

Based on the above, how likely is it that the errors are linked to the CPU?

I guess the answer is to run MemTest86+ with only one stick, then another, and see if the errors are the same?

If after a full test, I only see errors on CPU 0 and 13, would that rule out issues with memory sticks?

Comment: Yes, you should run MemTest86+ with only one stick, then another, and see if the errors are the same. And you should probably try reseating the CPU.

Comment: It *could* be that a cpu core is defective, but that it is across two very disparate cores suggests something in the memory controller or motherboard or RAM. I have seen evidence of defective cores but in that case it [was cores 14 and 15](https://superuser.com/questions/1505161/diagnosing-root-cause-of-single-core-failure/1505298#1505298) which would be a single physical core shared across two threads. I would look at disabling memory overclocking (EXPO or XMP) and seeing if stability improves, otherwise i've seen a lot of suspicious news about AMD motherboards having memory troubles...

Comment: @Mokubai thank you for your reply. Isn't the memory controller on the CPU itself for a Ryzen 3950X? It could also be the motherboard I guess but I have neither a spare motherboard nor a spare CPU to test :(

Comment: @Gantendo thanks for the suggestion. I'll check again if there is any bent pin. The latch does not seem to work well since everytime I lift the CPU cooler, the CPU gets lifted with it.

Comment: For testing purposes only, try lowering your ram speed to 2300 or so.  The RAM isn't storing data properly, I would guess the RAM is going bad.  Can you test the RAM in another PC?  Maybe try CPU-Z and compare the memory timing data found their with the memory timings found in your BIOS.  BIOS up to date?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I recently updated the bios after not doing it for a long time. New version was not even compatible with saved user profile anymore. I am still one version behind though

Comment: It looks like replacing the RAM, updating the BIOS and reseating the CPU after trying to clean the pins from whatever little dust was in some spots solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the RAM, updated the BIOS, and reseated the CPU after making sure to clean the pins from a bit of tiny dust here and there.

Memtest86+ no longer throws thousands of errors within 10 minutes.